# Add attribute to html and body

Tags: 8, theming

I need to add `class="no-trans"` to body, also edit the html tag.
How I can edit the `{{ html_attributes }}` and `{{ body_attributes }}` ?

my html.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </head>
  <body{{ body_attributes }}>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [attributes variable is an object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Template!Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8), that has some methods available.  One of them is `addClass()`, which allows you to add additional classes from a string or array.

```
<body{{ attributes.addClass('no-trans') }}>
```

To add arbitrary attributes to the html tag, you can use the `setAttribute()` method.  Multiple attributes can be set by chaining additional calls to `setAttribute()`:

```
<html{{ html_attributes.setAttribute('attrName1', 'attr1Value').setAttribute('attr2Name', 'attr2Value') }}>
```

---

Take a look at [the community documentation on using attributes in templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2513632).

You can also look at the [node.html.twig template in the classy theme](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/themes/classy/templates/content/node.html.twig) for an example of adding an array of classes with `addClass()`:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'node',
    'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
    node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
    node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
    not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
  ]
%}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using this setAttribute(... over just attr1="value" or addClass class="myClass" ?

Comment: Classes and attributes may already be added in preprocess, so if you add `class="..."` or `attr1="..."` directly in the template, the attribute may then appear twice in the output.  `setAttribute()` should also ensure that the value is correctly encoded for use as an attribute value, which may be important if it is a dynamic value.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a preprocess alternative (maybe you will need access to some info to make custom html classes).

```
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MODULE_OR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  if (is_array($vars['attributes'])) {
    $vars['attributes'] = new Attribute($vars['attributes']);
  }

  $vars['html_attributes']->addClass('goes-to-HTML-tag');
  $vars['attributes']->addClass('no-trans');
}
```